# How do I make "find" exclude the folder it searches in?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I'm running the following command:

```
find /var/www/html/content/processing -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I would like to delete all the folders under the `processing` folder (the processing folder should never be deleted).

The command is deleting the `processing` folder as well. How do I limit the script to delete *only* the folders under that folder?

Comment: posterity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13525004/how-to-exclude-this-current-dot-folder-from-find-type-d

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just add `-mindepth 1`, which will [skip the first depth hierarchy](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Directories) and thus leave out your parent directory.

Also, you don't need an extra `-exec` call to `rm`, you can [just `delete` the folders directly](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Deleting-Files.html) if they're empty.

```
find /var/www/html/content/processing -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 -delete
```

If they're not empty:

```
find /var/www/html/content/processing -mindepth 1 -type d -mtime +1 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

If you're lazy you can also have a wildcard expanded. Since `*` doesn't include the current directory by default ([unless `dotglob` is set](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)), you could also do:

```
find /var/www/html/content/processing/* -type d -mtime +1 -delete
```

However, this would also not include hidden folders, again due to the `dotglob` option.

Comment: Hi, I get "find: warning: you have specified the -mindepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-mindepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.
" and also "find: cannot delete `/folder/50d82faf0e09e': Directory not empty"

Comment: Add mindepth before type then. To delete the directories when not empty you can stick with the rm approach you had originally.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that find returns the current directory (.) along with the other directories, so it deletes the processing folder as well as the subdirectories. A quick way to get around that would be to append the option

```
-not -name .
```

which stops find from outputting the current directory, and in turn stops it from being deleted.

That would work if you were running the command within the processing directory, so to allow for the fact that you are using an absolute path:

```
-not -name /var/www/html/content/processing
```

And the whole command would be:

```
find /var/www/html/content/processing -type d -mtime +1 -not -name /var/www/html/content/processing -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: The last command is wrong. `-name` refers to basename, it never matches anything with a slash. You probably need to use `-path`.

Answer (score 3):

Already answered, still I would like to list another approach.

`find /var/www/html/content/processing -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d`

This will exclude top directory (and also sub directories), and now you can apply whatever command that we want to apply over it.

*>> Options:

-mindepth 1 : To exclude root directory

-maxdepth 1 : To avoid parsing sub directories. (For particular scenario as questioned, you don't need this).

-type d : List only directory types. This option should come after mindepth  maxdepth uses.*

Comment: Why `-maxdepth 1`? Why `-type d` twice? How is this different to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Attie: Thanks, corrected the mistake. maxdepth is not necessary, but it would be useful if you want to avoid listing sub-directories.